# vba excel userform won't show

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Morning all!

I'm having trouble getting a userfrom to show.

Below is the code I want to use. I declare the Userfrom (oUserform) as a public variable, initialize it and make the changes, then show it.

That's the plan anyway, however I get an error with oUserform.show, saying that the object doesn't support the property or method.

```
    Public oUserform As UserForm
    Public iNumberOfRecords As Integer
    Public iEndRow As Integer

Sub subIntialize()

    Set oUserform = frmbusinessimpact

    iEndRow = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    iNumberOfRecords = iEndRow - 1

    Call subPopulateRecordClass(iEndRow)

    With oUserform
        .TotalRecords = iNumberOfRecords
        .CurrentRecord = 1
        Call subUpdateUserform
    End With

    oUserform.Show

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `frmbusinessimpact`? Is it a name of an existing form?

Comment: Yes. It has not code on Initalize

Comment: Why not use it directly instead of declaring it? Is there a particular reason?

Comment: It works! When I used frmbusinessimpact.show instead of oUserform.Show and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Glad it works for you. If however you want to stick with your logic, you can try what @DougGlancy posted. :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to declare `oUserform` as an instance of `frmbusinessimpact` and use the `New` keyword.

```
Public oUserform As frmbusinessimpact
Public iNumberOfRecords As Integer
Public iEndRow As Integer

Sub subIntialize()

Set oUserform = New frmbusinessimpact

iEndRow = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
iNumberOfRecords = iEndRow - 1

Call subPopulateRecordClass(iEndRow)

With oUserform
    .TotalRecords = iNumberOfRecords
    .CurrentRecord = 1
    Call subUpdateUserform
End With

oUserform.Show

End Sub
```

The book [Professional Excel Development](http://books.google.com/books?id=VnegO0pMYlIC&pg=PA375&lpg=PA375&dq=userform%20professional%20excel%20development&source=bl&ots=DvHGPlTeRC&sig=Uor27NaZWefzSnegYR_pBJg4gJ4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=opIvU4aSD5H9oASNvoCIAw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=userform%20professional%20excel%20development&f=false) has a good chapter on how, and why, to code userforms this way. I've got a more specific example at http://yoursumbuddy.com/a-flexible-vba-chooser-form/.